# Redirecting to main page Opencart

Tags: php, opencart

After clicking on the item in the Opencart page, it will again redirect to the main page instead of the product description page. I have also added the manual route of the product page on URL as index.php?route=product/product&product_id=795 but still facing the same problem. I have also found that this page calls again and again till it gives error as "This page isn't working". Please help me with this.

Comment: I think you have to use suitable module with open cart version. See here. https://forum.opencart.com/viewtopic.php?t=53901

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass one extra variable something like this.

```
index.php?route=product/product&product_id=795&redirect=home
```

Now to go to `catalog/controller/product/product.php` and paste the given below code inside the index method. something like this.

```
public function index() {
     if (isset($this->request->get['redirect'])) {
            $this->redirect($this->url->link('common/home', '', 'SSL'));
        }
```

OR
if you want to change it dynamically with out custome url.then go to

`catalog/controller/product/category.php` and find this code.

```
'href'        => $this->url->link('product/product', 'path=' . $this->request->get['path'] . '&product_id=' . $result['product_id'] . $url)
```

And replace with

```
'href'        => $this->url->link('product/product', 'path=' . $this->request->get['path'] . '&product_id=' . $result['product_id'] . $url.'&redirect=home')
```

And `catalog/controller/product/product.php` will be as given above.